# Dynamically allocating a structure in C++ using malloc

Tags: c++, c, struct, malloc, allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
struct product{
        string productName;
        float price;
};

int main()
{
    struct product *article;
    int n=2; // n represent here the number of products
    article= (product*) malloc(n * sizeof(product));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> article[i].productName; // <=> (article+i)->productName;
        cin >> article[i].price;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout << article[i].productName <<"\t" << article[i].price << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why this is wrong, because when I try to run this I get a segmentation fault.  I used the GDB debugger to see which line is causing the problem, and this is the line that was causing this:

```
cin >> article[i].productName;
```

Why? This was bothering me for days...

Comment: Are you able to compile this code?

Comment: Treat this as an object lesson in why you don't use `malloc()` et al in C++ programs.

Comment: yes i can compile it, and @JonathanLeffler yes this is so helpful; i can't imagine how i could figure this out by my self thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you allocate memory with the `new` operator, it does two things:

1. it allocates memory to hold an object;
2. it calls a constructor to initialize the objects.

In your case (`malloc`), you do only the first part so your structure members are uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

`article[0]` is not initialized (i.e. the constructor of `struct product` has not been called for `article[0]`). Therefore, `article[0].productName` has not been initialized either.

Use `new product[n]` instead of `(product*) malloc(n * sizeof(product))` to initialize the array elements (and by transitivity the members of the elements).

Comment: @YassineBakkar use `std::vector<product> article(n);` . Then the memory will be freed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct product{
    string productName;
    float price;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 2; // n represent here the number of products
    product *article = new product[n];
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> article[i].productName; // <=> (article+i)->productName;
        cin >> article[i].price;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << article[i].productName << "\t" << article[i].price << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

article[0] was not initialized when you used `cin`. If you use `new[]` instead, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of malloc-ing object, use new

```
product *article = new product[n];
```

Comment: It would have to be an array `new`, wouldn't it?